# Difference between Web Application and Application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, heroku

I have built a music store program similar to iTunes in Java and and want to deploy it to the web. But when I go to Heroku App and see the demo application, its completely different. They say we need to upload a web application. Same thing in Google App Engine where they specify that we have to download the Google Plugin to Eclipse and the SDK and create a web application project.

I am using Eclipse and don't want to rewrite my whole application again?

Comment: What do you mean by "I have built a music store program similar to iTunes in Java"? Is this a desktop app?

Comment: yes i built it in eclipse as a desktop app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Web Application is a program coded in a server side language : PHP,ASP...JSP in java's case.
The difference is that a web application will reside in the server instead of the client's computer and will process everything in the server - but , the control of the program is left for the client. A good example for a web application is this site. When ill press "Post Your Answer" button , a command from my ,client side computer, will be sent to Stackoverflow's web application and all necessary things that should be processed to publish this answer will be processed on the Stackoverflow's server.

About your application, you have two options:

1. Seperate the UI from the inner logic and rewrite the UI as a Web Application
2. Not the best option: Convert your App to an Applet and embed it inside a web page(a part of your web app).

Comment: I would like to choose the 2nd Option as I don't know how to write a web application but please look at the latter part of this comment for the problems I am facing with the second option. I have to store some data as the users works through the app for the next time he opens the app. So is it better to store data in files or is their another option like using databases (MySQL, etc.). The problems I am facing with the second option are that I have a number of classes and am using some external jar archives. So can you tell me the code to embed it. Thanks for the help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have written your application using Swing, you will have additional code to write to get it to run as a web application.

What I would suggest is separating the presentation code from your model and business logic. If you can do that, you will then need to write a new presentation tier and then tweak your model/business logic code to support the server side architecture you decide to use.